# Executing an Arm Assembly program within a separate program

Tags: assembly, arm, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to write a program for my PI 4 that will Execute other programs all of the programs are written in ARM Assembly . the programs i am trying to execute turn on and off the GPIO Pins i will be using.

Instead of using a 7 page program i am trying to break it into smaller executable and have 1 master executable.

I have the have the individual files working but I have no clue on what code i would need to reference and execute another assembly program. i am compiling using EX:( gcc -o pin17on pin17on.s ).

how would i reference pin17on in arm assembly to execute that file?

Comment: if you are running on top of an operating system then you need to make a system call or use a library (like a C library) that you can call that will do the system call for you.  The system has to do it so there is no other way how you get to the system call is up to you.  system calls are operating system plus target specific so its not an arm thing it is a xyz operating system on arm thing.

Comment: Are you sure you don't just want to make a *function* that you *link* into a C program so you can call it as `my_function()` or whatever?  This lets you break your source up into multiple files but still have it simple to combine the parts into one program.

Comment: I have to use assembly for this final project i just need to run the file from another assembly file I have no clue how to go about it I normal learn by breaking apart someones code and i haven't found any examples